# How to install Ruby on RHEL 5.3

Tags: installation, ruby, yum, rhel-5

I am trying to install the latest Ruby on RHEL 5.3 with the following:

```
[root@anjanb logs]# yum install ruby-full
Repository engineering-update is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository engineering-install is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository emergency-update is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository emergency-install is listed more than once in the configuration
primary.xml.gz                                                                      |  12 kB     00:00
http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/i386/repodata/primary.xml.gz: [Errno -1] Metadata file does not match checksum
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/primary.xml.gz from adobe-linux-i386: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
[root@anjanb logs]#
```

What might be wrong, and how can I successfully install Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use ruby version manager to install ruby.  This works on all linux-based distros and will save you a lot of hassle in the long run.  I can't recommend it enough to be honest.  Have a look at the [installation instructions](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/).